# How to provide localized text?

Tags: iphone, localization

Is there a simple-to-get instruction on how to localize text on the iPhone? I have some strings which need to be present in a localized form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I translated my app by following [this tutorial](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/). It is hosted on a translation site but is applicable wether or not you use them to provide the translated text.